# how to scrape _ngcontent-c0?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write my first ever scraper and I'm facing a problem. all of the tutorials I've watched of course mention Tags in order to kind of catch the part you want to scrape and they mention something like this, or this is actually my code thus far, I'm trying to scrape the title, date, and country of each story:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import zip_longest

result = requests.get("https://www.cdc.gov/globalhealth/healthprotection/stories-from-the- 
field/stories-by-country.html?Sort=Date%3A%3Adesc")
source = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,"lxml")
```

--------------------------NOW COMES MY PROBLEM------------------------------------------
when I start looking to scrape the title it in a CDC Vietnam uses Technology Innovations to Improve COVID-19 Response like this!

When I try the code I learned :

```
title = soup.find_all("span__ngcontent-c0",{"class": ##I don't know what goes here!})
```

of course it doesn't work. I have searched and found this _ngcontent-c0 is actually angular but I don't know how to scrape it! Any help?
[image]

Comment: Soup maybe is too limited for this things. With selenium or playwright you can use "//span[count(@_ngcontent-c0)=1]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This web needs **javascript** to render all content you want to scrape.
It calls API to get all content. **Just request this API.**
You need to do something like this:

```py
import requests

result = requests.get(
    "https://www.cdc.gov/globalhealth/healthprotection/stories-from-the-field/dghp-stories-country.json")

for item in result.json()["items"]:
    print("Title: " + item["Title"])
    print("Date: " + item["Date"][0:10])
    print("Country: " + ','.join(item["Country"]))
    print()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Title: System Strengthening – A One Health Approach
Date: 2016-12-12
Country: Kenya,Multiple

Title: Early Warning Alert and Response Network Put the Brakes on Deadly Diseases
Date: 2016-12-12
Country: Somalia,Syria
```

I hope I have been able to help you.

Comment: this is really helpful thanks I'm getting somewhere! but some stories have more than one country listed like the second one for example has Africa and Côte d'Ivoire. how can I get the loop to basically mention the story twice once with each country? thanks a million!

Comment: Oh my god, it is wonderful! now I just need to figure out how to get this from my juptyr notebook into a csv file! but thanks this is the answer indeed!

Comment: did that thank you so much for being here and doing what you do it's great to junior programs like myself :)

Comment: oops sorry! I was too excited! I believe it's done now :)